# How do i add a logo to the right of the nav bar?

Tags: morea-framework

I want to add a logo to the top right corner of my morea generated pages.
I am not sure which file I need to modify or how, can you please advise?

Comment: Please consider adding the code you already tried so people can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Morea is based upon Bootstrap 3.3, so you'll need to use those CSS classes to provide a right-justified logo.

To insert a logo, you need to modify the code for the items in the navbar, which is located in the core.html file. Here is the code for the default navbar:

https://github.com/morea-framework/core/blob/master/src/_layouts/core.html#L69-L89

What you'll need to do is create a new itemized list right after the current list that creates a right justified navbar item. For example, I inserted this code starting on line 90 of that file in one of my local Morea sites:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>LOGO</li>
</ul>
```

And when I re-run morea-run-local.sh, the navbar looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, the formatting needs help, but you can investigate the Bootstrap 3.3 docs to figure out the best way to display your logo. Good luck!